# Use Python Multiprocess inside of a class taking way TOO long

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm with a problem using multiprocess with Python. I have two codes. The first is working well, but it's outside of a class and I need to put it inside of a class because this class is part of a bigger program. When I do it the code takes 250 seconds to run instead of 10 when is

The working code (without class) is:

```
import time
nlp =spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
start_time = time.time()
doc1 = nlp(str("Data Scientist"))


def get_paralel_similarity(item):
    return doc1.similarity(nlp(item))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    similarities = pool.map(get_paralel_similarity, list(df["jobs"])) 
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

--- 10.971235990524292 seconds ---
```

You can see that it took less than 11 seconds to run. Without multiprocessing, the same process was taking 1 minute.

The problem is, doc1 is dynamic and I need to run this code a large number of times. In that sense I need to put it in a class. The code I did with this objective is:

```
import time
import spacy
import warnings
import operator
from multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method
from functools import partial
from tqdm import tqdm

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
nlp =spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

def get_paralel_similarity(tup):
    #doc1 = tup[0]
    return tup[0].similarity(nlp(tup[1]))

class Matcher(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.word = kwargs.get('word')
        self.word_list = kwargs.get('word_list')
        self.n = kwargs.get('n')
        self.nlp = kwargs.get('nlp')

    def get_top_similarities(self):
        pool = Pool()  
        similarities = {}
        doc1 = nlp(str(self.word))
        tup_list = []
        for i in tqdm(self.word_list):
            tup_list.append((doc1,i))

        start_time = time.time()
        similarities = pool.map(get_paralel_similarity, tup_list)
        pool.close()
        #pool.join()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        simi = {}
        for i in tqd(range(len(self.word_list))):
            simi[self.word_list[i]] = similarities[i]
        return sorted(simi.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)[:self.n]
```

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_pickle("complete.pkl")

matcher = Matcher(word="Data Scientist",word_list=list(df["jobs"]),n=5,nlp=nlp)
similarity = matcher.get_top_similarities()
--- 256.1134169101715 seconds ---
```

It's taking ~250 seconds. I will appreciate it if you please help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: Why does it have to be a class? `Matcher` has only one method besides `__init__` so it could as well just be a single function.

Comment: I have no problem in changing it to a function as you propose but still have the same problem. The function needs to receive the doc1 parameter, do you have any hint on how to do it?

Comment: You mean like `def get_paralel_similarity(doc1, item)`? What is the problem with that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `get_top_similarities`. Why can’t you pass `doc1` to it instead of creating it inside?

Comment: Because the information comes from outside of this program, that's why I need a class or a function.